# I have 2 text areas. On consecutive clicks of add description button the text of both the textareas will get merged into the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am able to achieve this but I also need a time/date stamp along with each new entry.
Here's a fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/Anupriya24/pstynje9/

Script:

```
    var count=0;
$('.addDescBtn').on('click', function() {
    count++;
    if(count<=1){           
        if($("#description").val()==""){
            alert("Please add to existing description field.");
            $("#description").val("");
            $("#description").removeAttr("readonly");
            count=0; 
        }
        else {
            $("#descriptionHolder").append('<div class="form-group col-md-12 pad0 mar-t20" id="newDesc"><label class="col-md-3 pad0 visible-none" for="description1">Description:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="form-control col-md-9" id="description1" placeholder="Description"></textarea> </div>');
        }
    }
    if($('#descriptionHolder').find('#newDesc').length){
        var text=$("#description").val().trim();            
        var text1=$("#description1").val();         
        var combinedText=text+"\n"+text1+"\n";
        $("#description").val(combinedText);
        $("#description").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $("#description1").val(""); 
    }  

});
```

Html

```
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12 pad0" id="descriptionHolder">
                            <label class="col-md-3 pad0" for="description">Description:</label>
                            <textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="form-control col-md-9" id="description" placeholder="Description" ></textarea> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12 pad0">
                            <input type="button" class="addDescBtn orangeBtn btn fright" value="Add Description" id="addDescription"/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, could you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Please click on the add description button in the fiddle link after typing some text in the text area. Then a new text area will appear... Type some text there and click on add description again.. so the text in the 2 text areas will get merged and be there in the first one. I need the same thing along with the time/date stamp so as to reflect when is the new description added.

Comment: Do you want the user to type in the timestamp, or for it to detect the time their browser is set to?

Comment: Based on my understanding this would help you :
var text1=$("#description1").val() + new Date();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? https://jsfiddle.net/pstynje9/16/

```
var count=0, descs = [];
$('.addDescBtn').on('click', function() {
    if($('#descriptionHolder').find('#newDesc').length){
        descs.push(new Date().toString() + ':' + $("#description1").val());
    } else {
        descs.push(new Date().toString() + ':' + $("#description").val());
    }

    $("#description").val(descs.join('\n'));
    count++;
    if(count<=1){           
        if($("#description").val()==""){
            alert("Please add to existing description field.");
            $("#description").val("");
            $("#description").removeAttr("readonly");
            count=0; 
        }
        else {
            $("#descriptionHolder").append('<div class="form-group col-md-12 pad0 mar-t20" id="newDesc"><label class="col-md-3 pad0 visible-none" for="description1">Description:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="form-control col-md-9" id="description1" placeholder="Description"></textarea> </div>');
        }
    }

    $("#description").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    $("#description1").val(""); 

});
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
   var count=0;
$('.addDescBtn').on('click', function() {
count++;
if(count<=1){           
    if($("#description").val()==""){
        alert("Please add to existing description field.");
        $("#description").val("");
        $("#description").removeAttr("readonly");
        count=0; 
    }
    else {
        $("#descriptionHolder").append('<div class="form-group col-md-12 pad0 mar-t20" id="newDesc"><label class="col-md-3 pad0 visible-none" for="description1">Description:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="form-control col-md-9" id="description1" placeholder="Description"></textarea> </div>');
    }
}
if($('#descriptionHolder').find('#newDesc').length){
    var text=$("#description").val().trim();            
    //Just added new Date() with your string; It will give current timestamp.
    var text1=$("#description1").val() + new Date();        
    var combinedText=text+"\n"+text1+"\n";
    $("#description").val(combinedText);
    $("#description").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    $("#description1").val(""); 
}  

});
```

Comment: This will work but I want the date to stand out and start from a new line each time... If I give :  var text1=$("#description1").val() +"\n"+ new Date();
Then spacing after the first entry is different from the rest.